# Load dropdown list with navigation property depend on another dropdown list

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

My Project model class is like this

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmptyProjectName")]
    [Display(Name = "ProjectName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))] 
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmptyCountry")]
    [Display(Name = "Country", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))] 
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Province")]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources),
    ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmptyProvince")]
    [Display(Name = "Province", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))] 
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

My create view is like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Project</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("CountryId", string.Format("--- {0} {1} ---", @Resources.Resources.Select, @Resources.Resources.Country))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProvinceId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("ProvinceId", string.Format("--- {0} {1} ---", @Resources.Resources.Select, @Resources.Resources.Province))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProvinceId)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value=@Resources.Resources.Create  />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Here I need to load the "Provinces" that exists in the "Country". i.e when country is selected, provinces that exists in the selected country need to be loaded to the province drop down.

For this case I've added script like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
        $("#CountryId").change(function () {
            debugger;
            $("#ProvinceId").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ProjectController/GetProvincesForCountry/", /

                dataType: 'json',

                data: { countryId: $("#CountryId").val() },

                success: function (provinces) {

                    $.each(data, function (i) {
                        var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                data[i].Id + '">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
                        $("#ProvinceId").append(optionhtml);
                    });

                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    debugger;
                    alert( ex.toString());
                }
            });
            return false;
        })
    });
</script>
```

Here is my method in controller

```
public JsonResult GetProvincesForCountry(int countryId)
{
    return Json(db.Provinces.Where(x => x.CountryId.Equals(countryId)).ToList());
}
```

But when I'm selecting country from the drop down message comes [Object object]

Here is my Country,province model classes

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Province
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }        

    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `$.each(provinces, function (i) {` - `provinces`, not `data`. And note you should return just a collection of anonymous objects containing only the data you need in the view - `var data = db.Provinces.Where(x => x.CountryId.Equals(countryId)).Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }); return Json(data);`

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your guide solved my problem. Thanks million.